# How to evaluate this$ \int_{0}^{c} y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, beta-function

How do I evaluate the following integral?  $$ \int_{0}^{c} y^{\alpha-1} (1-y)^{\beta-1}dy $$  where $1\geq c>0$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: NB for $c = 1$ this $B(\alpha, \beta)$, where $B$ is the Beta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: MathWorld [Incomplete Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

Comment: Is there anything which I could improve that discourages you from accepting my answer?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by *Somos* within the comment section this is the so-called [Incomplete Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) denoted as

> $$B(z;a,b)=\int_0^z t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$

Further note that for $z=1$ this equals the [Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $($as mentioned by *Travis*$)$

$$B(a,b)=\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$

The Beta Function $-$ and the Incomplete Beta Function aswell $-$ are special functions and cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions $($such as polynomials, logarithms, etc.$)$ in a finite combination. So the integral

$$\int_0^c y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}dy$$

cannot be "evaluated" in the classical sense as long as the numbers $\alpha,\beta,c$ are choosen arbitrarily. You may look up the two links for further information especially concerning their different ways of representation.

Comment: @andrew No problem! Make sure to mark it as accepted if your are satisfied with the given answer :)